# How to capture table level data changes in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse

I have high volume of data normalized into more than 100 tables. There are multiple applications which change underlying data in those tables and I want to raise events on those changes. Possible options that I know of are:

- Change Data Capture
- Change Tracking
- Using Triggers on each table (bad option but possible)

Can someone share the best way of doing this if someone has already done this before?

What I really want in the end is if there is one transaction that affected 12 tables off 100 I should be able to bubble one event up instead of 12. Assume there are concurrent users change these tables.

Answer (score 0):

Two options I can think of:

1. Triggers ARE the right way to capture change events in the DB layer
2. Codewise, I make sure in my app that each table is changed through only one place in the code, regardless what the change is (I call it a hub for that table, as it channels many different pathways into one place), it becomes very easy to catch change events that way in the code layer

Comment: You cannot rely on #2. Data in databases is often changed outside the application. It is short-sighted to believe otherwise which is why constraints, auditing, fks etc must be enforced by the db unless you want your data to be bad.

Comment: @HLGEM Really depends on the design of the APP, right? I like all my data sources to be accessed through only **one** place, always.

Comment: I agree with HLGEM on that front. We deal with set of legacy apps some written C#, C++, PowerBUilder and some SPs are public interface for 3rd party products (Bad design I know) but looking at that we dont have one source to monitor data changes. Thats the Challenge! Regarding Trigger 2 bad things: 1. They are unmanageable (with 400 tables) 2. They do have impact on SQL Server performance.

Comment: @Rajat Mehta - indid, that changes the picture. Still, I think triggers is the safest way (**safe**, not *fast* or *manageable* which is a matter of how you design it)

Comment: Triggers can be realtively fast if designed correctly. Judt because you think only one source will hit the database doesn't mean that is true. I guarantee no one is going through the application to make a large data update or insert. It is foolish to plan for only the data layer affecting data.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is SQL Server Query Notifications: [Using Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you want to 'batch' multiple changes, I think you should follow the route of **Change Data Capture** or **Change Tracking** (depending on whether you just want to know that something changed or what changes happened).

They should be used by a 'polling' procedure, where you poll for changes every few minutes (seconds, miliseconds???) and raise events. The nice thing about this is that as long as you store the last rowversion of the previous poll -for each table- you can check whenever you like for changes since the last poll. You don't rely on a real time triggers approach, that if halted you would loose all events forever. The procedure could be easily created inside a procedure that checks each table and you would need only 1 more table to store last rowversion per table.

Also, the overhead of this approach would be controlled by you and by how frequently the polling happens.